# Get XMP Rating by using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, photoshop, xmp

How can I get the rating existing in an xmp file by using AppleScript. 
The xmp file belongs to an CR2 file. I tried it by using the photoshop cc 2017 library. But I don't get it work.

Answer (score 0):

I've always found exiftool to be handy for reading/writing XMP

http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

If you need to access it from AppleScript then you can use something like:

```
set theFile to choose file
set theInfoFromExiftool to do shell script "/usr/local/bin/exiftool -CreateDate " & quoted form of POSIX path of theFile
```

Of course, you'll need to change CreateDate to the name of whatever tag you're interested in.

Hope that's of some help.